# Openlayers: Get Start and End Points of Line Vector Features

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, kml, line

I'm trying hard to get start and end of lines from a vector. The line vector is loaded from a kml-file. For now, I tried to iterate over features in the vector and grab the start point and put it in a markers array, and then add to the map, but without success. The console.log shows me that the markers array is of length 0..

This is what I tried so far ([live](http://gimoya.bplaced.net/Openlayers/Trails/map_exp_2.html)):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>OPEN TRAILS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="defaultstyle.css" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body: {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .olControlAttribution {
            bottom: 3px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0;">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="output-id"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadError = function() { this.style.display="none";}

        var map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' );
        var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM({numZoomLevels: 12});

        //default styles for vector layers
        var styleTrails = new OpenLayers.Style({
                /*label: "${name}",
                fontColor: "#909090",
                fontSize: "12px",
                fontFamily: "Verdana",
                fontWeight: "bold",*/
                strokeColor: "#F8D71C",
                strokeWidth: 4,
                strokeColor: "#F62700",
                strokeOpacity: 0.6,
                cursor: "pointer"
            })


        var KMLtrails = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                "default": styleTrails,
                // selected style
                "select": {
                    strokeColor: "#1F5AFF",
                    cursor: "pointer"
                    }
                }),
            projection: map.displayProjection,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "Trails.kml",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    extractStyles: false, 
                    extractAttributes: true,
                    maxDepth: 2,
                })
            })
        });

        KMLtrails.events.on({
            featureselected: function(event) {
                var feature = event.feature;
                var name = feature.attributes.name;
                var desc = feature.attributes.description;
                var output = "<span style='font-family:Troika; font-size:24px;'>-- Info --</br></span>" + desc;
                document.getElementById("output-id").innerHTML = output;
                map.zoomToExtent(event.feature.geometry.getBounds(), closest=false);
            },
            featureunselected: function(event) { 
                document.getElementById("output-id").innerHTML = null;
            } 
        }); 

        var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(KMLtrails);
        map.addControl(select);
        select.activate();

        function StartMarkers() {       
            var features = KMLtrails.features;
            var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
            var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
            var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png', size);
            for( var i = 0; i < features.length; i++ ) {
                var startPoint = features[i].geometry.components[0];
                markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(startPoint.x, startPoint.y), icon));
                }   
            return markers; 
        }

        var Markers = StartMarkers();
        console.log(Markers);
        map.addLayers([KMLtrails, Markers, osm]);

        KMLtrails.events.register("loadend", KMLtrails, function (e) {
            map.zoomToExtent(KMLtrails.getDataExtent());
        }); 
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

PS: This is a closed and rephrased [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93996/openlayers-issue-with-line-start-points), which obviously didn't gain any attention..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working script:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>OPEN TRAILS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="defaultstyle.css" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body: {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .olControlAttribution {
            bottom: 3px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0;">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="output-id"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadError = function() { this.style.display="none";}

        var map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' );
        var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM({numZoomLevels: 12});

        //default styles for vector layers
        var styleTrails = new OpenLayers.Style({
                /*label: "${name}",
                fontColor: "#909090",
                fontSize: "12px",
                fontFamily: "Verdana",
                fontWeight: "bold",*/
                strokeColor: "#F8D71C",
                strokeWidth: 4,
                strokeColor: "#F62700",
                strokeOpacity: 0.6,
                cursor: "pointer"
            })


        var KMLtrails = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                "default": styleTrails,
                // selected style
                "select": {
                    strokeColor: "#1F5AFF",
                    cursor: "pointer"
                    }
                }),
            projection: map.displayProjection,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "Trails.kml",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    extractStyles: false, 
                    extractAttributes: true,
                    maxDepth: 2,
                })
            })
        });

        KMLtrails.events.on({
            featureselected: function(event) {
                var feature = event.feature;
                var name = feature.attributes.name;
                var desc = feature.attributes.description;
                var output = "<span style='font-family:Troika; font-size:24px;'>-- Info --</br></span>" + desc;
                document.getElementById("output-id").innerHTML = output;
                map.zoomToExtent(event.feature.geometry.getBounds(), closest=false);
            },
            featureunselected: function(event) { 
                document.getElementById("output-id").innerHTML = null;
            } 
        }); 

        var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(KMLtrails);
        map.addControl(select);
        select.activate();

        var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
        var size = new OpenLayers.Size(10,10);      

        function StartMarkers(layer) {      
            var features = layer.features;
            for( var i = 0; i < features.length; i++ ) {    
                var singleLine = features[i].geometry.components[0];
                var endPts = singleLine.getVertices(nodes = true);  //if nodes = true is set only start and end points will be returned..
                console.log(i);
                console.log(features[i].attributes.name);
                console.log(singleLine);
                markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(endPts[0].x, endPts[0].y), new OpenLayers.Icon('http://gimoya.bplaced.net/Openlayers/Icons/pin.png', size)));
                markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(endPts[1].x, endPts[1].y), new OpenLayers.Icon('http://gimoya.bplaced.net/Openlayers/Icons/pin.png', size)));
                }
            }

        KMLtrails.events.register("loadend", KMLtrails, function (e) {
            map.zoomToExtent(KMLtrails.getDataExtent());
            markers = StartMarkers(KMLtrails);
        }); 

        console.log(markers);

        map.addLayers([KMLtrails, osm, markers]); 

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You call StartMarkers before you add your KMLtrails layer to the map. KMLtrails.features is empty because it hasn't been loaded. If you set a breakpoint at var feature = event.feature; in your featureselected function you will see the features are loaded.

I'd suggest setting Markers to StartMarkers after you've loaded the KMLtrails and osm layers.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Lowther, I already tried this (see updated source of the live example). I also tried to put the StartMarker function within the registering of the KMLtrails loadend - but still no success..

Comment: Hmm. I see from your updated live example that KMLtrails still isn't loaded when called, but when I set a breakpoint in the function registered for loadend and I go to the console KMLtrails.features has the features there. Can you update your live example to call StartMarkers in the loadend?

Comment: I've put the call to the loadend and now I also add the layer to the map here.. the log tells me the array was filled, at least partly - strangely some of the points have LonLat set to NA. However, the markers are not rendered..

Comment: At line markers.addMarker... startPoint is a LineString. If you want the start point you should use features[i].geometry.components[0].components[0]. To get the endPoint you would grab the last index of the features components (var eIDx = features[i].geometry.components[0].components.length - 1;) and then use that: endPoint = features[i].geometry.components[0].components[eIdx];

Comment: `features[i].geometry.components[0].components[0];` is undefined.. please see update.

Comment: Here (http://gimoya.bplaced.net/Openlayers/Trails/map_exp_3.html) I tried it with `getVertices(nodes=true)`, which actually works within the function registered for loadend of KMLtrails - However, I can't add the marker layer to the map inside this function. And when defining Markers outside it won't work either because the layer hasn't loaded when called..

Comment: Finally got it - thanks @Dave Lowther! I just needed to make the variable `markers` global!